# How to use Regex to extract the URLs and Image URLs in DataFrame Python

Tags: python, html, regex, url

I am trying to use Regex in Python to extract the URLs and Img between greater-than and less than sign.
I have a dataframe as below:

| PopupInfo | OID |
| --- | --- |
| <img src="https://doc-00-90-mymaps.googleusercontent.com/ height="200" width="auto"/> | 1 |
| <img src="https://doc-0c-90-mymaps.googleusercontent.com/> <br br> http://hfasia.blogspot.com/2017/02/pla-oth-sw-radar-network-and-its-300-km.html <img src="https://doc-0k-90-mymaps.googleusercontent.com/ height="200" width="auto" /> | 2 |
| Michael 20 JX https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates | 3 |
| Owen | 4 |

My expectation is that I would like to separate them into 2 columns in DataFrame:

| URLs | Img |
| --- | --- |
| Null | <img src="https://doc-00-90-mymaps.googleusercontent.com/ height="200" width="auto"/> |
| http://hfasia.blogspot.com/2017/02/pla-oth-sw-radar-network-and-its-300-km.html | <img src="https://doc-0c-90-mymaps.googleusercontent.com/> <img src="https://doc-0k-90-mymaps.googleusercontent.com/ height="200" width="auto" /> |
| https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates | Null |
| Null | Null |

Due to the first time I use this function, I've found something and applied it to my problem to find the <Img.....>

```
def returnImg(link):
ret = re.search(r'\<(.*?)\>',str(link)).group(0)
return ret
returnImg(df['PopupInfo'])
```

I got this error:

[image]

I also tried something to get the URls:

```
def Find(string):

regex = r"(?i)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'\".,<>?«»“”‘’]))"
url = re.findall(regex, str(string))
return [x[0] for x in url]
```

My result displayed included the URLs inside Img and ignore the URLs links in the same row and also the order of dataframe (row without links).

[image]

What should I do to get my expectation?

Comment: Your HTML tags appear to be malformed, with missing ending double quotes.  Did you copy it over to your question here correctly?

Comment: The image links have too many characters so I shortened it

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use `str.extract` here:

```py
df["URL"] = df["PopupInfo"].str.extract(r'(https?://[^\s">]+)')
```

Comment: Thank you in advanced. It helps a lot. About the other case, How could I extract the <img.......> ? Is it the same or need any further analyst? The problem is that Some rows do not contain only 1 <img.......> and it also has something like break <br> <br> between the img links